# How to accept and reject Incoming call using customized buttons in android 10?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I'm using `ConnectionServices` but am unable to get how to accept and reject buttons work.
Here am trying `ITelephony` services but as it is deprecated in `API level 29` it doesn't work. Suggest to me any good technique or example of call accept and reject function that works in android 10.
Here is my customized activity code

```kotlin
class CallReceiver : AppCompatActivity()  {
    private lateinit var binding: CustomScreenBinding

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = CustomScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        keyguardManager = getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE) as KeyguardManager
        audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        val telephony = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
        val contactName = intent.getStringExtra("u_name")
        Log.i("name", "name" + contactName)
        binding.name.text = contactName
        val contactNumber = intent.getStringExtra("u_number")
        Log.i("number", "number" + contactNumber)
        binding.number.text = contactNumber

        val intent = intent
        val id = intent.getLongExtra("u_id", 0)
        Log.i("data", id.toString())

        val contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id)
        val displayPhotoUri =
            Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO)
        try {
            val fd = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r")
            val buf = fd?.createInputStream()
            val my_btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf)
            binding.photo.setImageBitmap(my_btmp)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
        }


        val telephonyService: ITelephony
        val tm = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)

            val c = Class.forName(tm.javaClass.name)
            val m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony")
            m.isAccessible = true
            telephonyService = m.invoke(tm) as ITelephony
            val bundle = intent.extras
            val phoneNumber = bundle!!.getString("incoming_number")
            Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber!!)

        binding.buttonHangup.setOnClickListener {

                    telephonyService.endCall()
                    Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber)


        }
        binding.buttonAnswer.setOnClickListener {
            telephonyService.answerRingingCall()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

android is imposing restrictions on what an App can do and cannot. meaning by that you don't have the entire control over the call management, and i think that's why you are unable to get how to accept and reject buttons.

I think the only solution for that is to build your own call app which will give you entire control over the call management.

follow this documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged

Comment: I am trying to build an app like Colour Call Screen just want to accept and reject button functionality to accept the incoming calls and my custom screen finish on receiving and displaying the default android screen.